# Passing an Intent from activity to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

How can I pass an Intent received in my activity to a fragment? 
I have this method in my activity that create a new Fragment when the activity receive a new Intent.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_principale, new BumpFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Then, in the fragment class I have this method that works on new Intent received by the activity:

```
        private void searchForBump(){

                boolean inNoleggio = prefs.getBoolean(Keys.IN_NOLEGGIO, false);

                if (!inNoleggio) {

                    Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
                    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                        Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelabl

    eArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                    NdefMessage message = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[0];
                    String payload = new String(message.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
                    String[] data = payload.split(":");
                //other stuff 
}
```

This method is called in fragment's onStart and on Resume methods.
Is this code and the logic correct? Because testing the app, when the intent is received nothing happens. Naturally in app's manifest I put the intent-filter for the activity

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the intent values in fragment as argument

on activity pass the argument as bundle
fragment.setargument (data);
data is a bundle instance

In fragment you can retrieve this argument in activity created callback method in fragment

Access the activity method in fragment through getActivity with type casting of your activity name